# Spark HiveContext get the same format as hive client select

Tags: apache-spark, hive

When a Hive table has values like maps or arrays, if you select it in the Hive client they are shown as JSON, e.g.: `{"a":1,"b":1}` or `[1,2,2]`.

When you select those in Spark, they are map/array objects in the `DataFrame`. If you stringify each row they are `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 1)` or `WrappedArray(1, 2, 2)`.

I want to have the same format as the Hive client when using Spark's `HiveContext`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? 1.6?

Comment: @stefanobaghino spark 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Spark has its own functions to convert complex objects into their JSON representation.

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) is the documentation for the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` package, which also comes with the `to_json` function that does the following:

> Converts a column containing a StructType, ArrayType of StructTypes, a MapType or ArrayType of MapTypes into a JSON string with the specified schema. Throws an exception, in the case of an unsupported type.

Here is a short example as ran on the `spark-shell`:

```
scala> val df = spark.createDataFrame(
     |   Seq(("hello", Map("a" -> 1)), ("world", Map("b" -> 2)))
     | ).toDF("name", "map")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, map: map<string,int>]

scala> df.show
+-----+-----------+
| name|        map|
+-----+-----------+
|hello|Map(a -> 1)|
|world|Map(b -> 2)|
+-----+-----------+

scala> df.select($"name", to_json(struct($"map")) as "json").show
+-----+---------------+
| name|           json|
+-----+---------------+
|hello|{"map":{"a":1}}|
|world|{"map":{"b":2}}|
+-----+---------------+
```

Here is a similar example, with arrays instead of maps:

```
scala> val df = spark.createDataFrame(
     |   Seq(("hello", Seq("a", "b")), ("world", Seq("c", "d")))
     | ).toDF("name", "array")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, array: array<string>]

scala> df.select($"name", to_json(struct($"array")) as "json").show
+-----+-------------------+
| name|               json|
+-----+-------------------+
|hello|{"array":["a","b"]}|
|world|{"array":["c","d"]}|
+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: great!!  But I saw to_json is added since Spark 2.1. Have any idea in 1.6 version?

Comment: You'd have to write your own UDF for that. You mentioned in a comment that you are using Spark 2.1.